# MonoTouch.Dialog: how can a navigation control surround an HtmlElement?

Tags: html, mono, xamarin.ios, navigation

For this code:

```
    var Root = new RootElement("ConnectionView") 
    {
    new Section("Sales") 
    { 
            new HtmlElement("Discover more about foo",
                            "http://foo.com")
        }   
    }

    var dvc = new DialogViewController(Root, true);
    this.NavigationController.PushViewController(dvc, true);
    this.AddChildViewController(dvc);
    this.View.AddSubview(dvc.View);
```

The dialog is created as expected, with headers and elements.

However, although the HtmlElement opens the URL as anticipated, it navigates the app to a full-screen display of the web site without any navigation methods for returning to the dialog proper. Other elements that open views retain the navigation controller as expected and do not open full screen.

Note: I am using the flag on the DialogViewController to enable Nav.

Answer (score 0):

Without doing much work, the simplest thing to do is to make sure that your DialogViewController is hosted in a UINAvigationController, which will provide a simple way of going back.

Alternatives include subclassing the HtmlElement and adding your own UI to control that.

Comment: I believe that it is: see the 3 additional lines of code that accompanies the implementation you reviewed.

Comment: @miguel.de.icaza - Is there an easy way to get to the navigationbar of the navigationcontroller that contains the webview that displays when tapping an HtmlElement? I am trying to customize the back button etc.